# Math font similar to Latin Modern Math, but with extended support

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode-math

Hi I am quite new to XeLaTeX, and I would like to use `unicode-math` because I recently realised that PDFLaTeX was unable to display certain symbols.

However this came with a few issues. When displaying vectors, I wanted bold italics vectors, so I used `\symbfit`. This worked fine with letters, however there are no bold italics numbers, e.g. `\symbfit{0}`.

I would like to know if there is a math font that is somewhat similar to Latin Modern Math (as I like the original font), but supports more symbols?

Thanks, and I hope I am making sense.

Just as a guide, this is what Latin Modern Math looks like, and notice how 0 is not bold or italics:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math} % This is the default font
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[range={bb,bbit}, Scale=MatchUppercase]

\begin{document}
    \begin{gather*}
        \symbfit{A}\symbfit{v} = \symbfit{b} \\
        \mathbb{1}\symbfit{A} = \symbfit{A} \\
        T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m \\
        T\left( \symbfit{0} \right) = \symbfit{0}
    \end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

I'm using `TeX Gyre Pagella Math` solely for the double struck R and 1.

[image]

Comment: It's unusual to use bold italic digits in math. As far as I know, they aren't defined in unicode math, so the `unicode-math` package has no support for them. For zero vectors it is customary to use bold upright zero digit: `\symbfup{0}`.

Comment: as Segei says Unicode bold italic only has https://mathml-refresh.github.io/xml-entities/2007doc/bold-italic.html  so the fonts do not have digits in this block, you could of course use a matching bold italic text font if you really wanted that.